# sublimeREPL can not import _ctypes

Tags: python-3.x, sublimetext3, sublimerepl, pyperclip

I'm trying to `import pyperclip` in a python REPL tab of sublime text 3, but I get the following error:

```
Python 3.5.1 (v3.5.1:37a07cee5969, Dec  6 2015, 01:54:25) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pyperclip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\a\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\pyperclip\__init__.py", line 31, in <module>
    from .clipboards import (init_osx_clipboard,
  File "C:\Users\a\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\pyperclip\clipboards.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .exceptions import PyperclipException
  File "C:\Users\a\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\pyperclip\exceptions.py", line 1, in <module>
    import ctypes
  File "C:\Users\a\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array
ImportError: Module use of python33.dll conflicts with this version of Python.
```

It turns out that I can't import _ctypes at all:

```
>>> import _ctypes
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: Module use of python33.dll conflicts with this version of Python.
>>>
```

Same imports work on a command prompt or IDLE, so why not in sublimeREPL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the following related issues on GitHub:

- https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL/issues/457
- https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL/issues/296
- **https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL/issues/140**

The issue occurs when I try to run commands directly in REPL instead of executing a file. In issue 140 a patch has been suggested<strike>, but it's for ST2. I don't know how it applies to Windows and ST3</strike>. Actually it was very easy to apply the patch, I just needed to find the right file. On my Win 10 machine I had to go to `%APPDATA%/Sublime Text 3/Packages/SublimeREPL` (not the same as main installation folder) and edit the `sublimerepl.py` file as described in the patch.

Comment: Thanks, @MattDMo! I was able to fix it easily. I just needed to know that it's fixable, I guess. :)